# Finite module over Noetherian ring faithfully flat?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

If I have Noetherian rings $B=A^G\subset A$ (for some action of finite group $G$, maybe not relevant) and $A$ is finite as $B$-module.

Is it always true that $A$ is faithfully flat over $B$?

EDIT: Since the link in the comments provides counterexamples, is this true if the action of $G$ comes from a morphism of varieties $X=\mathrm{Spec}(A)\to \mathrm{Spec}(B)$ and $G$ acts freely on $X$?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/169052/are-quotients-of-affine-schemes-by-finite-groups-faithfully-flat

Comment: Thanks. I stumbled across this question in Mumfords "Abelian Varieties", where he uses this as a fact. Is it true if the action is free? (I'll edit accordingly)

Comment: What do you mean by "the action is free"?

Comment: Hmm...actually the action on the variety $X$ is free and we suppose $X=Spec(A)\to Spec(B)$